# Is there a way to alert the user to a insert into ... duplicate update entry?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

New to PHP/MySql - and am learning by trying to make a database to store some string entries.

All working fine - I have three user entries in my form: `class`, `keywords`, `usrstring` which are added to my database without a problem.

Two issues, though:

**#1)** This is the mysql function I'm using:

```
$sql = "INSERT  INTO `reporting` (class, keywords, usrtext) VALUES (\"$class\", \"$keywords\", \"$usrtext\") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `usrtext` = \"$usrtext\"  ";
```

But I want a `duplicate key update` only if both the `class` and `keywords` match a row. Not an OR instance, where if either `class` or `keywords` match, the row is updated. Is this the correct syntax to achieve the AND instance?

**#2** I'm sending the form data via an ajax post, which re-directs back to the main index page as follows:

```
$("#formdata").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "posted.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#formdata").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
             window.location.href = 'index.php?=successfullyadded';
             alert(data) ;
             $("#formdata")[0].reset(); // reset form and clear all hidden inputs

       }
         });

});
```

How can I interrupt the process to create an alert/prompt on the original form page so that the user is notified of the duplicate entry, and is given an option to continue to update the entry to cancel (giving them a chance to change the `class` or `keywords` before entry is completed?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: So you'd have a composite key on (class,keywords), right? (Although of course in a normalised environment you would never have a column called keywords)

Comment: @tadman - Thanks for the warning and references. I am indeed using `mysqli` and have read about proper scrubbing of inputs with character escaping (though many people seem to imply that character escaping is not enough). So far, I've been practicing only on a xampp localhost environment to keep things safe.

Comment: @Strawberry - yes, I would have a composite key to update **if** both class and keywords were duplicated, only the usrstring column would get updated. I think my `$sql` syntax will update if either class or keywords is duplicated though...

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, use prepared statements and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind data. That's the safest method and doesn't require a lot of work. `?` in your query becomes a value that's always escaped properly if you define your types correctly, but that's usually obvious and easy.

Answer (score 0):

my code is for alert message when a user register with an already registered email. Alerting when email is duplicate.

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email='$Email'");
            $numrow = mysql_num_rows($sql);

```
        if($numrow > 0){


        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("That Email is already exits !!Try another Email");
        history.back();</script>';

        }
        else{

            $staffInsert_sql = mysql_query("Insert Into admin(name,gender,password,confirmpw,email,address,reg_date)
                VALUES ('$Name','$gender','$password','$confirmpw','$Email','$Address',now()
                )");
            if ($staffInsert_sql) {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\"> alert('Save Successfully One Record');</script>";
                header("location:success_register.php");
            }
        }
```